# Select commannd in Visual Basic not working properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, ms-access

I am new to Visual Basic for Applications. I have a login system in my current program. You will understand the system by reading below. I have an Access database whose table looks like following :-

```
Name : Cookies
----------------------------
ID     |   Nme  |    Val   | 
----------------------------
```

The table is cleared and all the contents of it is deleted when the form is closed. Now, when a user signs in, a row is added :-

```
----------------------------
(id)   | "user" | username |
----------------------------
```

Now, the user enters his id and password in the form index.vb and the command to add the row in the access database is also there in the index.vb file. After the row is added, the index.vb file is hidden and the file userpage.vb is shown. Now, I have seen this that when the user logs in, the row is added properly in the access file (by refreshing the access file manually) and everything is deleted properly in the table when the window is closed. So, there is no problem in inserting and deletion of rows. So, obviously, the problem is with the displaying part. My code for displaying the username is as follows (the code is in the userpage.vb file) :-

```
Dim Username As String = ""
Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Software\db.accdb")
Conn.Open()

Dim Cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Val From Cookies Where Nme='user'", Conn)
Dim Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader
Do While Reader.Read
    Username = Reader.Item("Val")
Loop
Label1.Text = "Welcome " & Username
Conn.Close()
```

The output that is given is "Welcome" and Username is "" even when the row has been added. Now, I have also seen this by experimenting that when I manually add a row in the access database with the same details that is going to be added in the database problematically, the program works fine. Any help, of course, will be appreciated and thanks for reading this long post.

**UPDATE 1** ( as suggested by @Dimple)
My code for insertion is as follows(This code is in the index.vb page) :-

```
    Dim usernameinput As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Cmmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Cmmd.Connection = Conn

    Cmmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cookies (Nme, Val)  Values('user','" & usernameinput & "')"
    Cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim Userpage As New User_page
    Me.Hide()

    Userpage.Show()
```

Comment: Could the issue be that in your select command you have 'user' hard-coded?  Shouldn't you have that as a variable?  (or better yet, a parameter to avoid SQL Injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that Access displays row after manually refreshing Access file (database). Sometimes you need to Requery() the database after insertion. I had this problem while working with Access.

```
Form1

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\db.accdb")

        Conn.Open()
        Dim usernameinput As String = "TextBox3.Text"
        Dim Cmmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        Cmmd.Connection = Conn

        Cmmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cookies (Nme, Val)  Values('user','" & usernameinput & "')"
        Cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class


Form2

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\db.accdb")

        Conn.Open()
        Dim usernameinput As String = "TextBox3.Text"
        Dim Cmmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        Cmmd.Connection = Conn

        Cmmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cookies (Nme, Val)  Values('user','" & usernameinput & "')"
        Cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I didnt even change the variables you named. Just avoided form designing by using msgbox.

Comment: Ok..w8 for a while. I am updating my question

Comment: Are you keeping the Access Database open while performing the operations? Try executing your code with Access Database Closed. I will implement your code here and see if there is any other problem.

Comment: Dimple - the same thing with MS Access closed

Comment: Dear Ben, Everything is working fine here at my end. I executed your code using two different forms and I get the Username perfectly alright. You also said something about deleting the table. Are you doing that through code? If yes, may be you are accidently emptying the table before displaying username form.

Comment: Not working for me Dimple...do not know why. thanks for your help though..upvote for your help

Comment: Don't be disappointed. If you wish I would like to see the code you have written. I have moved to MySql and Sql Server now. Still, if I would be of any help. I run your code using Access 2007 and VS Express 2010.

Comment: I DO NOT KNOW WHAT WAS THE PROBLEM BUT REDOING THE CODE IN A NEW PROJECT SOLVED THE PROBLEM

Answer (score 0):

My brother instead of using,

```
Do While Reader.Read
    Username = Reader.Item("Val")
Loop
```

try

```
Do While Reader.Read = True
    Username = Reader.Item(0)
Loop
```

Let me Know if it works for you.